# I have a flutter function to add markers to GoogleMaps with text from the Firestore database

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

I am able to add the markers to the map but when I try to add the name of the place in the infowindow, only one name appears on all the infowindows. My intention is to have a different name for each infowindow.

Here's the code for the function

```
 _handleTapOrig() {
    LatLng tappedPoint;


    setState(() {
      

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bus_stages').get().then((value) {
        if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          for (int i = 0; i < value.docs.length; i++) {
            DocumentSnapshot snap = value.docs[i];
            GeoPoint geoPoint = snap.get("location");
            double mylat = geoPoint.latitude;
            String jje = snap.get("stage_name");
            double mylng = geoPoint.longitude;
            LatLng mypoint = LatLng(mylat, mylng);
            setState(() {
              _mylatlng.add(LatLng(mylat, mylng)
              );
            });
           ///Add markers
            myMarker = [];
            _mylatlng.forEach((element) {
              tappedPoint = element;

              myMarker.add(Marker(

                markerId: MarkerId(tappedPoint.toString()),
                position: tappedPoint,
                icon: myBitmapDescriptor,
                /// BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan),
                infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Bus Stage ${snap.get("stage_name")}",
                    snippet: 'Tap Google directions button to navigate to stage'),
              ));
            });

          }
        //  print(_mylatlng);
        }
      });

     
     
      // print('List of Markers: $myMarker');
    });



  }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, The relevant DB is Cloud Firestore . Please if you have an idea, I'll be glad to receive your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Maybe this video can help you regarding : [Flutter - Google Maps - Geolocation, Markers with firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hg8CT3ysFjY)